# How to set proxy in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy

I am currently facing one issue can you please help to fix this. how can i set my proxy becoz i am getting **Connect timed out** i have put screenshot for reference and thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First you should have a proxy and its port. Then select manual proxy in above screenshot.

Comment: @C.F.G can you please explain more

Comment: Do you know what is a proxy? proxy is something like ip address `123.222.256.111` that makes most websites recognize your connection as a foreign country user depending on the proxy.

Comment: and what about login and password and how can I get port

Comment: but I don't save any proxy in internet.

Comment: Usually, most proxies do not require a password. It needs just a port number and ip address.

Comment: Do you really need to set proxy? why?

Comment: @C.F.G I don't know above i updated my studio flamingo to giraffe after the update it give me an error

Comment: So, No need to set proxy. just make sure that your internet connection is OK and make sure you have installed gradle and sdk correctly.

Comment: all things are working fine I checked my internet, and it's working, and the same project I cloned in another system it's clone and work fine

Comment: check these files: `gradle.properties` and `local.properties`. if there is any non-commented commands about proxy, comment them. This is all I can say using your provided info.

Comment: Okay i will check and Update you

Answer (score -1):

To set up a proxy in Android Studio, follow these steps:

1. Open Android Studio:
   Launch Android Studio on your computer.
2. Go to Preferences or Settings:
   On macOS, click on "Android Studio" in the menu bar, and then select "Preferences." On Windows, go to "File" in the toolbar, and then select "Settings."
3. Search for Proxy Settings:
   In the search bar at the top left corner of the Preferences/Settings window, type "proxy." This will help you quickly locate the proxy settings.
4. Configure Proxy Settings:
   You should see an option for "HTTP Proxy" or "HTTP Proxy settings." Click on it to configure your proxy settings.
5. Choose the Proxy Type:
   Android Studio typically supports Manual and Auto-detect proxy settings. Choose the appropriate option based on your network configuration:

   - Manual: If you know the proxy server and port information, select this option.
   - Auto-detect: Android Studio will attempt to automatically detect the proxy settings if this option is available.
6. Enter Proxy Information:
   If you selected the "Manual" option, enter the proxy server and port information. You may also need to provide a username and password if your proxy server requires authentication.
7. Test the Proxy Connection (Optional):
   Some proxy settings allow you to test the connection to ensure it's working. Use this option if available.
8. Apply and Save Changes:
   After configuring the proxy settings, make sure to click the "Apply" or "OK" button to save the changes.
9. Restart Android Studio:
   To ensure that the changes take effect, restart Android Studio.

Your proxy settings are now configured in Android Studio, and it should use the specified proxy server for network connections. Keep in mind that if you're behind a corporate network or firewall, you may need to consult with your IT department for the correct proxy server information and any necessary authentication details.

Comment: can you please tell ne which username and password?